# I cannot seem to use my variable in my random number generator

Tags: arrays, swift, variables

Ideally I am trying to set a TextField input to a variable shortestWait and another to longestWait where I will then be able to use them in a random number generator between shortestWait and longestWait.

```
@State var shortestWait = 30
@State var longestestWait = 60

@State var randomInt = Int.random(in: shortestWait...longestWait)
```

I expected this to work, however I got the following error:
Cannot use instance member "shortestWait" within property initializer property initializers run before self is available.

Comment: The error message means exactly what is written, you cannot use "shortestWait" in declaring `@State var randomInt = Int.random(in: shortestWait...longestWait)`,
because at the time of `randomInt` initialization, the other properties are not yet fully initialized, and this leads to the error. Similarly for "longestestWait".
You can initialize `randomInt` in `init()` or `.onAppear {...}` or other functions,  but not where you have it. Alternatively you can use a computed property.
For example, try `.onAppear { randomInt = Int.random(in: shortestWait...longestWait) }` .

Answer (score 0):

workingdog told you the problem. You can't have one property's initial value depend on another property's initial value like that. Instead, so something like this:

```
@State var shortestWait = 30 {
    didSet {
        calcRandomInt()
    }
}
@State var longestestWait = 60
    didSet {
        calcRandomInt()
    }
}

@State var randomInt = Int.random(in: 30...60) // The initial value is a throw-away.


func calcRandomInt() {
    randomInt = Int.random(in: shortestWait...longestWait)
}
```

Comment: This has some fragility. If you change the initial value of `shortestWait`, for example, but you forget to make the corresponding change to the initial value of `randomInt`, you now have a bug.

Comment: @HangarRash, true. Do you have a better suggestion? (Not to be snarky. I can't think of a better solution off the top of my head.)

Comment: I've done next to nothing with SwiftUI and @State variables. Can you initialize `randomInt` in an `init`?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using a `computed property`, such as in this example code. Whenever `shortestWait` or `longestWait` is changed in the TextFields, the `randomInt` will also be changed automatically.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var shortestWait = 30
    @State var longestWait = 60
    
    // computed property
    var randomInt: Int {
        if shortestWait < longestWait {
            return Int.random(in: shortestWait...longestWait)
        } else {
            return Int.random(in: longestWait...shortestWait) // <-- for you to determine
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            Text("random: \(randomInt)")
            TextField("shortest wait", value: $shortestWait, format: .number).border(.green)
            TextField("longest wait", value: $longestWait, format: .number).border(.red)
        }
    }
}
```